# Conditionally add _id field to mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
var concert = new models.concert({
    name: request.body.name,
    date: request.body.date,
    city: request.body.city,
    location: request.body.location,
    programme: request.body.programme
});
console.log("<< Concert to attempt save on: " + concert);
if (request.body._id) {
    console.log("Received _id field from body: " + request.body._id);
    concert._id = ObjectId(request.body._id + '');
}
```

But, the log tells me that:

```
<< Concert to attempt save on: 
{ 
    _id: 572312a289a4d8d810eed717,
    programme: 'to be announced',
    location: 'J.Nepomuk-Kapelle',
    city: 'Vienna, Austria32',
    date: 1464382800,
    name: 'Chamber Music Concert' 
}
```

The docs do say that mongoose will automatically assign an `ObjectId` to a model if it has none, but I expected it to happen at e.g. save/update, but it seems to happen on model instantiation.  What I want is my `_id` to be automatically assigned only if one was not received from the client, or if it was received with a `0` value. Is this possible? Thanks.